# how to disable one specific character being highlighted opaque red in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I began to code in the dark and couldn't see what keys I was typing, so when trying to use the shortcut to copy 'ctrl + v' I must have pressed the wrong key combination and caused this. I tried disabling 'unicode highlight' to no avail. I was wondering if someone could help. Included is a screenshot, the offending character is the letter 'v'.[screenshot of visual studio code, highlighted letter = 'v'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSigl.png)

Comment: Have you tried to close the search bar (upper-right) where "V" is typed in for search? Or pressing "Esc"?

Comment: I have now, and that resolved the issue. Sorry for being such a neophyte. I have no idea how I even opened the search bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That highlight is coming from the find widget (top right corner of your window), where you've typed "V" in case-insensitive search mode, which is why your "v" in the editor is being highlighted. If you don't want that to be highlighted anymore, either clear the search input of the find widget, or close the find widget.